# How do i handle touch events properly in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, multi-touch

**Scope of the project**

When a user touches the Android screen with two fingers, draw a "Frame" at each touch location with a "cursor" for each frame. Each frame is a custom slider that the cursor will move up and down. All the way up will be 100%, middle will be 0% and all the way down will be -100%. This will be used to control small motors, similar to tank turning, each touch controls a separate motor (sending signals over bluetooth). After a two touch and everything is drawn, I want to be able to lift off either finger, BUT keep the cursor at what ever location it was last at, while the other finger is free to move its cursor. When the last finger is lifted off, everything "hides" and resets to 0%.

**Functionality Wanted**

1. On two finger touch, draw separate .pngs under the touch location
2. After the frames and cursors are drawn, keep track of where they are relative to the frame to determine the percentage.
3. If a finger is lifted off, keep that fingers cursor at last known location, but the other finger can move it's cursor. Also if the finger is put back down it should be able to move its cursor again.
4. If both fingers are lifted off of the screen, hide everything and reset percentages to 0%

**Functionality Obtained**

- I can draw the frames and cursors on multitouch
- Positions and percentages work fine
- Cursors do move properly

**What doesn't work**

- I am unsure if I should have one custom class that handles both touch event or if i should have 2 instances of the custom class each handling their own touch events (I have tried both, the only way i get any "real" functionality is with 1 custom class handling both touch events, the other way doesn't work as intended)
- When I only have 1 custom class, It works great, but I have it "hide" everything if both fingers are not on the screen, and sometimes android registers that I have lifted a finger off the screen and this causes me a lot of issues when the frames hide then re appear in a different location
- When I use 2 custom classes I touch each custom class would have its own touch event, and i wouldn't have to worry about multitouch if i split the classes evenly between the screen. This was not the case, still need to deal with multitouch

Can someone explain to me how android handles their touch events. from what I have done, it seems if i lay down finger 1, the finger 2, the first finger will register a "ACTION_DOWN" and the second will register a "ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN", BUT if i life off my first finger, my second finger is "demoted" and now all of the events my second finger registers does not related to "ACTION_POINTER_2" and instead will be "ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, etc". Is this correct?

TouchUI.java

```
    package com.robota.android;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchUI extends ImageView {

public static final String LEFT_TOUCHUI = "com.robota.android:id/leftTouchUI";
public static final String RIGHT_TOUCHUI = "com.robota.android:id/rightTouchUI";
private String whoAmI = new String();
private MyPoints framePts = new MyPoints();
private MyPoints cursorPts = new MyPoints();
private Bitmap frame;
private Bitmap cursor;
private int frameWidth;
private int frameHeight;
private int cursorHeight;
private boolean pointerDown = false;
private int dy;

public TouchUI(final Context context, final AttributeSet as){
    super(context, as);
    Log.d("TouchUI", getResources().getResourceName(this.getId()));
    whoAmI = new String(getResources().getResourceName(this.getId()));
    if(whoAmI.equals(LEFT_TOUCHUI)){
        frame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tank_left);
    }else if(whoAmI.equals(RIGHT_TOUCHUI)){
        frame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tank_right);
    }
    cursor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cursor);
    frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
    frameHeight = frame.getHeight();
    cursorHeight = cursor.getHeight();
}

public void determinePointers(int x, int y){
        framePts.setOrigin(x-frameWidth/2, y-frameHeight/2);
        cursorPts.setOrigin(x-frameWidth/2, y-frameHeight/2);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Log.d("TouchUI", ">>>>> " + whoAmI);
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        determinePointers(x,y);
        pointerDown = true;
    }else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        pointerDown = false;
    }else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        dy = (int)e.getY()-framePts.getY();
        if(dy <= 0){
            dy=0;
        }else if(dy+cursorHeight/2 >= frameHeight){
            dy=frameHeight;
        }
        sendMotorSpeed(dy);
    }
    return true;
}

public void sendMotorSpeed(int dy){
    float motor = dy;
    motor-=frameHeight;
    motor*=-1;

    motor = (motor/frameHeight)*255;

    PacketController.updateMotorSpeeds(whoAmI, (int)motor);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if(pointerDown){//twoDown){
        canvas.drawBitmap(frame, framePts.getX(), framePts.getY(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cursor, cursorPts.getX(), (cursorPts.getY()+dy), null);
    }
    invalidate();
}

private class MyPoints{

    private int x = -100;
    private int y = -100;
    private int deltaY = 0;;

    public MyPoints(){
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public void setOrigin(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getDeltaY(){
        return deltaY;
    }

    public void setDeltaY(int newY){
        deltaY = (newY-y);
        Log.d("TouchUI", "DY: " + deltaY);
    }
}
}
```

Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.robota.android.TouchUI xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/leftTouchUI"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </com.robota.android.TouchUI>
    <com.robota.android.TouchUI xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rightTouchUI"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </com.robota.android.TouchUI>
</LinearLayout>
```

RobotController.java (Main Activity Class)

```
    package com.robota.android;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class RobotController extends Activity {
// Tag used to keep track of class in the Log
private static final String TAG = "robotController_new";
// Boolean to debugging
private static final boolean D = true;

// Intent request codes
private static final int DISCONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int CONNECT_DEVICE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

// Handler Codes
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 2;

// Local Bluetooth Adapter
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
// Bluetooth Discovery and Datahandler
private BluetoothComm btComm = null;

// Debug's TextView, this is where strings will be written to display
private TextView tv;
private ScrollView sv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "++ON CREATE++");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "NO BLUETOOTH DEVICE");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    PacketController.controller = this;
}


public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "++ON START++");

    if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }else{
        // Start BluetoothComm
        if(btComm == null){
            setupComm();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates new Bluetooth Communication
 */
private void setupComm(){
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+++setupComm+++");
    btComm = new BluetoothComm(this, handler);
}

private void connectDevice(Intent data){
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "+++connectDevice+++");
    String addr = data.getExtras()
        .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(addr);
    if(D) Log.d(TAG,"REMOTE ADDR: "+ addr);
    btComm.connect(device);
}

private void disconnectDevice(){
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "---disconnectDevice---");
    if(btComm.getState() == btComm.STATE_CONNECTED){
        btComm.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent serverIntent = null;
    switch(item.getItemId()){       
    case R.id.insecure_connect_scan:
        // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
        serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        try{
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, CONNECT_DEVICE);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFound){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start DeviceListActivity(Insecure)");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch(requestCode){
    case CONNECT_DEVICE:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            connectDevice(data);
        }
        break;
    case DISCONNECT_DEVICE:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            disconnectDevice();
        }
        break;
    }
}

public Handler getHandler(){
    return this.handler;
}

public BluetoothComm getBtComm(){
    return this.btComm;
}

// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(D) Log.d(TAG, "check message");
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "trying to read message");
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "bytes: " + readBuf + " arg1: " + msg.arg1 + " Message: " + readMessage);
            tv.append(readMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "trying to send message");
            String sendMessage = new String(String.valueOf(msg.obj));
        }
    }
};
}
```

Any other classes not listed I didn't believe needed to be, but if they are needed please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to save the pointerId's of each point and compare them to the new Id's given with each MotionEvent. It's slightly tricky to explain, so I'll point you to this [ADB Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) that explains it much better than I could. Long story short? Multitouch can be tricksy, but it's not as bad as it looks at first glance.

Comment: But does the motionEvent.getPointerIndex(PointerNumber) return the proper touch if I touch with my first finger, touch with my second finger, then lift my first finger. Is my second finger index 0, or index 1? And will it stay that index throughout???

Comment: Well, the index can change. The Id will stay persistent, so use that to refer to. To find out what the Index for a given pointer is for the -current- MotionEvent only, use findPointerIndex(id). Make sure to reread the section on "Index vs Id" in the link I gave.

Comment: Ok, that article is helping me slowly understand, but what I am not getting is, am I supposed to arbitrarily pick a pointer ID for each touch? This line mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);, confused me because is 0 referring to the first finger down or is it a number the coder picked to represent the first finger down? Does that mean my second finger down needs to be 1 and possibly my third finger would be a 2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not arbitrary. The line you pointed out is inside the ACTION_DOWN case. ACTION_DOWN is only triggered when the first finger presses down. Second, etc, will throw an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN instead. So, he's using 0 there because he knows there's only one index in the event, and he wants the first(and only) one. What you should do is save the ID for each finger any time you get a DOWN-type action. When you get a MOVE-type or UP-type action, run a findPointerIndex() for each saved ID. Then you have an index you can use to call getX/Y(index). Don't forget to remove the ID on UP events also.

Comment: Ok, I am really sorry but I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding still, thank you so much for your patience. The findPointerIndex() requires an ID to get an index correct? But then the method getPointerId() requires an index? This seems very circular to me... :P. So do I just need to assign an ID to my first finger (ex: 0) and assign an ID to my second finger (ex: 1)? Or which method do I use to get the initial ID of a touch, without the requirement for an index? Again, thanks for your patience with this stuff.

Comment: Take a look at the following line from that post: final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
You can use the mask and shift operation here to get the index for the *current* pointer that is interacting on a POINTER_UP/DOWN. For a simple ACTION_UP/DOWN, just use index 0 as above, because there's only one in that event. Then get the Id with getPointerId()

Comment: That makes sense. Ok. So on a ACTION_DOWN index is 0 because there is only 1 finger down. So then I will use getPointerId(index) to obtain the first ID. Then on an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, I will use the mentioned method to get the index of the second finger, and use getPointerId(index) to obtain the second ID. That makes sense. Now these ID's will change though right? Or after getting the IDs they don't change?

Comment: Well the ID's will stay the same throughout a gesture(from first down to last up), but not after that. The index can change on every MotionEvent, though, and that's why you need to get the indexes on every event and check them against your saved IDs

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much for all the help, and your patience. I am going to give this all a try and see if I can't get the functionality I am looking for tonight.